# How to round up to multiple of 4?

Tags: numerical-methods

I know how to round up to the number base 10 but I do not understand here, "multiple of 4"?

and the Question is "round 0xDEA24A20 up to multiple of 4" it is the base 16 not 10.

Could anyone give me some hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose the number in question is labeled x:

1. y := x // 4 (ignore the remainder)
2. z := x - 4y
3. If z is less than 2, then your result is 4y. Otherwise, your result is 4y + 4.

Let's use 50 as an example.

x = 50

y = 50 // 4 = 12

z = 50 - 48 = 2

So the result is 4y + 4, which equals **52**.

Comment: I realize that my notation may not be perfect, but this is the general process. Please edit where you see appropriate.